# Finding nth biggest value in a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have been trying to figure out how to return the key which has the nth biggest value in a nested dictionary. What causes problems for me is if there's some missing values like

```
my_dict = {'0': {'name': 'A', 'price': 50}, '1': {'name': 'B', 'price': 20}, '2': {'name': 'C'}, '3': {'name': 'D', 'price': 10}}
```

If every price existed, I could use code such as this to get the correct key:

```
sorted_list = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda item: item[1]['price'])
print(sorted_list[-number_im_using_to_find][1]['name'])
```

How to account for missing values in an efficient way?

Comment: `key=lambda item: item[1].get('price', 0)`?

Comment: As you don't really need keys, you can sort just values: `sorted(my_dict.values(), key=lambda x: x.get("price", 0))`

Comment: if you need just to find the maximum don't use _sorted_ but _max_, it has the same signature and it is more performant

Comment: Thank you @OlvinRoght for an alternative perspective. It definitely makes more sense to use values() instead of items().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to achieve this:

```
get(key[, default])
```

> Return the value for key if key is in the dictionary, else default. If default is not given, it defaults to None, so that this method never raises a KeyError.

Here is a code implementation using `dict.get`:

```
default_value = -1
key = lambda item: item[1].get('price', default_value)
sorted_list = sorted(my_dict.items(), key=key)
```

If you want just sorted values you could remove entirely the index `[1]`:

```
default_value = -1
key = lambda value: value.get('price', default_value)
sorted_list = sorted(my_dict.values(), key=key)
```

---

**EDIT**: if you want to be sortable with `NoneType` in the list, you could use something like:

```
>>> mylist = [3, 1, None, None, 2, 0]
>>> mylist.sort(key=lambda x: x or -1)
>>> mylist
[None, None, 0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Is there a document reference for the bottom note? I get `TypeError` from `sorted([None, 1])`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. actually `sorted` checks for `.__lt__(other)` and `.__gt__(other)` so it's not possible to compare with `NoneType`

Answer (score 1):

Use `get` with a default value, in this case 0 or even a negative value to put the elements with missing prices all the way down the sorted list.

```
lambda item: item[1].get('price', 0)
```